# How to check if token has transaction charge(i.e token is deflationary)

Tags: ethereum, web3js, binance, cryptocurrency

Before making a transaction via web3 i wanted to check if token is deflationary. Do we have any common method for erc20 token contracts to check  whether they are deflationary or not. I checked the abi for several defalationary tokens but thay don't seem to have any common method amongst them

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard that would define a general way to recognize a deflationary token.

The logic can be processed in many ways:

- Part of the `transfer()` and `transferFrom()` functions
- A separate `burn()` function

  - executable by an authorized address
  - executable by each token owner allowing them to burn their own tokens
  - can use any name - `burnFrom()`, `removeTokens()`, `lowerSupply()`, ...